# Excel GCD function giving strange results

Tags: excel, excel-formula, greatest-common-divisor

I'm working on a formula to reduce fractions in Excel.  The numerator and denominator are in separate cells. The numerator is in cell `I38` and has a value of 1015. The denominator is in cell `I40` and has a value of 100000.

I'm trying to use the GCD function to determine when I can reduce the fraction.

However, the GCD function is returning crazy results:
[image]

Am I misunderstanding the GCD function and how it works or is there a bug in Excel?

MS Excel 2016 on Windows 10, if that helps.

EDIT: When cell I38 has a number in it, the formula works fine. When it has a formula in it, the wrong answer is returned.  Here is a screenshot of the formula:
[image]
Here is the formula:

```
=G38*10^IF(C39=INT(C39),0,LEN(MID(C39-INT(C39),FIND(".",C39,1),LEN(C39)-FIND(".",C39,1))))
```

Comment: @JvdV I think you're misreading the image. The first value is in the cell I38 (letter I) and the value is 1015. The second value is in cell I40 and the value is 100000. The dialog box you're looking at is the results of Excel's built-in GCD function.

Comment: If you're getting the correct result... perhaps it is a problem with my version of Excel. Or, maybe it is because the cells I'm using are calculated and not just numbers.

Comment: Yes, I'm getting the right results. See [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8BGE.png). I'm in Excel 365 though so I can't verify for Excel 2016. Calculated fields didn't change that. Can you show you calculations?

Comment: @JvdV I changed the screenshot above to show the formula.

Comment: excel 2013 returns a value of 5

Comment: I just checked on my workstation's Excel 2016 Windows 10 version and it also is correct, but note how I get the option to enter a 3rd number immediately after entering a 2nd. I don't know whats wrong here.

Comment: are the values in I38, and I40 manually enter or are they the results of a formula? Is cell formatting (ie, numerical formatting to only display thousands accuracy) applied to either of the cells or is it set to general?  What happens if you enter the values into in the formula instead of the cell address?

Comment: @JvdV When cell I38 has a number in it "1015" everything works fine. When it has a formula in it, the wrong answer is returned.  I will edit in a screenshot of the formula.

Comment: @JvdV it's fixed!  I will edit solution above.

Comment: @BoltBait I wasn't much help but glad you fixed it!

Comment: Out of curiosity why refer to cell G38 instead of cell C39 in your formula?

Comment: This spreadsheet is a kind of "show your work" for my kid's math teacher.  I use it to show him the steps required to solve homework problems.  When converting a percent to a fraction, the first thing you must do it put your number over 100, then scale it up to remove any decimals. Then, you can reduce the fraction for your final answer.

Comment: @BoltBait It's better to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) and mark it as answered than to edit the answer into your question, which leaves the question "unanswered".

Comment: @chthonicdaemon I was actually planning on deleting it, since it turned out to be so simple. But, if you think there is value in keeping this around I will answer it.

Comment: @BoltBait The fact that you took this long to figure it out tells you it's not that simple. I'll bet this has bitten many people and they would appreciate a clear answer on SO. You'll be saving thousands of hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was I forgot to cast the result of that formula to INT (even though the result of the formula was always going to be an INT, Excel didn't see it that way).  Once I added that, everything worked fine:

```
=INT(G38*10^IF(C39=INT(C39),0,LEN(MID(C39-INT(C39),FIND(".",C39,1),LEN(C39)-FIND(".",C39,1)))))
```

Thanks goes out to user @JvdV for helping me track that down in the comments.